# Rails User Rating Another User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, rating

I am working on an application where a user has the ability to leave feedback on another user. Currently, I already have an implemented user model.

Is this considered a self referential association?

This seems a bit wierd to me (how to set it up through Active Record Associations).

How would I go about setting this association up, what type of association is it? Anything I need to watch out for while going about this (tips, suggestions, errors that may come up)?

## According to Answers Below Would This be the Way?

### (one to many between users and ratings and one to one between ratings and user)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :ratings
end

class Ratings < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may not be in Rails/Active Record terms but ORM generic.

I would probably implement this by having a Feedback or Review model and your User model would have one-to-many Feedback/Reviews and the Feedback/Review would have a one-to-one relationship  with the User who created it.

EDIT: Response to question update...

You can have an User object on the Ratings model that is the author. My rails experience is minimal but I believe your Ratings model would look like this.

```
class Ratings < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_one :user
end
```

Comment: Agreed.  Any time you find yourself associating a table with itself, you should stop and ask yourself if that association is a candidate for being a model of its own.  In this case, it absolutely should be.

Comment: thanks guys. I updated my original question to a revised version. I'm not sure how to implement a one to one and one to many when a :user is used 2 times. For example in the one to many, you have a user that has_many :ratings and a Rating belongs_to a :user 

To me it seems from that, that i can't get the original user who submitted a rating on another user. What tables would I use in this case?

Would the ratings table have the rating:integer feedback:text user_id:integer? But what about the receiver of the rating? How do I specify their data in there? Sorry I'm a bit confused. Hope its clear

Comment: thanks flash. I ended up getting it working. I will update with the code I used soon. 

I used the code I had put originally though to get it working. I did a nested association in my routes file. 

map.resources :users, :has_many => :ratings

this did the trick when I had the association as in my original post. I appreciate the help though. Your answer helped me do it.